# Lower verbosity of Powershell command to minimal form

Tags: powershell

I'm executing the following in one of my Powershell scripts:

```
New-Item -ItemType Directory -Path "MyFolder"
```

The output looks something like this:

> ```
> PS C:\> .\example.ps1
>
>
>        Directory: C:\
>
>
>    Mode                LastWriteTime     Length Name
>    ----                -------------     ------ ----
>    d----         12/7/2015   9:52 PM            MyFolder
>
>
>  
> PS C:\>
> ```

That's a whopping total of *eight* lines of output. My script runs as part of a Task in my msbuild file, and space for Output in Visual Studio is limited, so this is quite an annoyance.

Now I understand I can pipe output to `Out-Null` to supress *all* of those lines, but I do like *some* feedback about the command taking place. One line of feedback would be optimal.

I guess this workaround could work:

```
Write-Host "Creating folder MyFolder"
New-Item -ItemType Directory -Path "MyFolder" | Out-Null
```

But it's tedious to remember/write this all the time.

I guess another workaround would be to create some kind of wrapper functionality, but then again since `New-Item` is just an example, I'd have to write many wrappers. Instead, I'm looking for a technique that works across the `***-Item` cmdlets.

Is there any way to lower verbosity of commands like `New-Item` a bit, without having to resort to workarounds?

I've gone through [the `New-Item` documentation](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849795.aspx) but found no clue. Perhaps my workaround is the only way to accomplish this?

***Bottom line***: Is there an idiomatic way to condense `New-Item` output to one line?

Comment: Have you looked into piping the output into one of the `Format-*` cmdlets?

Comment: @RyanBemrose Hmm, no, hadn't thought of that. Which one would you recommend? The only one that seems applicable is `Format-Custom` and (if/when I might get it to work) would amount to something similar to @sodawillow's answer, right?

Comment: My answer is not very orthodox but it allows you to output the desired message

Comment: `$null = mkdir MyFolder`?

Comment: I asked because `Format-*` is the idiomatic way to control output, but I'm not sure how to do what you're asking with it.  I think your best bet is to use @sodawillow's technique (expanded in my answer) to transform the output object on the pipeline from `DirectoryInfo` to `String`, which displays much more tersely.

Comment: @Mathias OP wants a simple way to output a custom message instead of the standard one, not suppress it completely

Comment: All of this output that you are concerned with is defined in an XML file. If you really don't like the standard output of a DirectoryInfo object you could change what is output by default for that kind of object. `Get-Help Update-FormatData` and look at `$env:windir\system32\windowspowershell\v1.0\*format.ps1xml` for examples, and look at [Writing a Windows PowerShell Format File](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg580944(v=vs.85).aspx). That won't change the properties of the object, just the default output.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The pipeline output for `New-Item` is a `System.IO.DirectoryInfo` object, and the default handling for sending a `DirectoryInfo` to the console is the verbose output you see.

```
PS> cd d:\temp
PS> $output = New-Item -ItemType Directory -Path "MyFolder"
PS> $output

    Directory: D:\temp

Mode                LastWriteTime     Length Name
----                -------------     ------ ----
d----        2015-12-07     13:15            foo
```

(The `$output` variable here is superfluous; I'm only using it in examples to shorten the line and to avoid creating a bunch of new directories while testing. :)

One way to reduce the verbosity is to use a pipeline filter to output only the data you're interested, rather than the entire `DirectoryInfo`.  Formatting it as a string, the output only takes one line.  Usually this would be the property `Name` or `FullName`

```
PS> $output | Select-Object -ExpandProperty FullName
D:\temp\MyFolder
```

When creating a log file, it's also useful to know what the operation was.  You can use `foreach` to create a custom string from the DirectoryInfo objects.

```
PS> $output | % { "Created directory '$($_.Name)' in parent '$($_.Parent.FullName)'" }
Created directory 'MyFolder' in parent 'D:\Temp'
```

And, if you intend to do this a lot, you can even create a shorthand filter function for it.

```
PS> filter Format-DirectoryOperation($verb) {
>>    "$verb directory '$($_.Name)' in parent '$($_.Parent.FullName)'"
>>  }
PS> $output | Format-DirectoryOperation('Created')
Created directory 'foo' in parent 'D:\temp'
```

Answer (score 2):

The idiomatic way would be to expand the `Name` (or `FullName`) property of the created object:

```
New-Item 'foo' -Type Directory | select -Expand FullName
```

If you need this frequently you could wrap it in a custom function like this:

```
function New-Folder {
  [CmdletBinding()]
  Param(
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
    [ValidateNotNullOrEmpty()]
    [string]$Path
  )

  New-Item $Path -Type Directory | Select-Object -Expand FullName
}
```

and put that into your [profile](http://blogs.technet.com/b/heyscriptingguy/archive/2012/05/21/understanding-the-six-powershell-profiles.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

Why not simply :

```
New-Item -ItemType Directory -Path "MyMyFolder" | % { Write-Output "Directory created !" }
```

Comment: This is at the least preferable to my current workaround, good suggestion! I'd tweak it to `{ Write-Output "Created $_" }` or something similar. Absent a Powershell-built-in way to decrease verbosity / condense output, this might be the best approach for my case...

Comment: At least you make use of the foreach loop. You still can access the created object properties AND you have your own message ;-) all of this in a one-liner

Answer (score 0):

If you're writing a script, I would recommend using try-catch. That way you know for sure if it worked or not. It's a little more coding, but definitely worth doing if there is a possibility of the script not running as expected.

```
try {
  New-Item -ItemType Directory -Path "MyFolder" -ErrorAction Stop | Out-Null
  Write-Output "Created folder MyFolder"
}
catch {
  "Failed to create folder MyFolder"
}
```

Comment: Thx for the suggestion on the try-catch. But for the core issue / question I tried to ask your answer is the same as my current workaround, isn't it? Or am I missing something?

Comment: With mine you won't get the success output unless it actually is successful. But otherwise, yes, they are similar.

Answer (score 0):

Here are a few other techniques for changing the output of PS cmdlets. One is via `format.ps1xml` files (`help about_format.ps1xml`). .PS1XML files don't actually target the output of cmdlets directly, they target output from the various format methods. The format-* cmdlets correspond to the various format methods. The format-* cmdlets (either explicitly or implicitly) are used to display instances of selected .NET types. So by modifying or creating a .PS1XML file you effectively change how object instances coming out of *-item cmdlets are displayed.

Another technique is to wrap or proxy cmdlets. Here's [a blog](http://blogs.technet.com/b/heyscriptingguy/archive/2011/03/01/proxy-functions-spice-up-your-powershell-core-cmdlets.aspx) that describes this.

Another possibility to write your own "PS Provider" (try `get-psprovider` to see existing providers). The *-item cmdlets are specifically designed to work with both built in and add-on providers. By writing your file system provider, you can exert a lot of control over the *-item cmdlets. You would need to come up with another drive letter convention than C:, D:, etc. since that one is already used. But hopefully your MSBUILD files don't have too many hardcoded drive letter uses.

Answer (score 0):

I'm surprised not to see something as simple as

```
$output = New-Item -ItemType Directory -Path "MyFolder"
"$output"

d:\test\MyFolder
```

Casting the DirectoryInfo as a string converts it to the one-line name, embedd this in a command in a string:

->

```
PS D:\t\> "Creating folder: $(New-Item -ItemType Directory -Path 'MyFolder')"

Creating folder: D:\t\MyFolder
```

which can be shortened with aliases for command line typing ->

```
"$(ni -i d MyFolder)"
```

->

```
"$(md MyFolder)"
```

but, as commented, "*Instead, I'm looking for a technique that works across the ___-Item cmdlets.*" is unlikely to happen, because the problem is not the cmdlet being verbose, it's to do with the return value of the cmdlet, and *that* can vary depending on which PSProvider you're using. In this case it returns a DirectoryInfo, but if you did `cd variable:\; $r = New-Item -ItemType directory -Value test -Name test` the return is a PSVariable type, and so on for other things.