# How do you hide the "GAC/Version/Location" headers from PowerShell scripts?

Tags: powershell

When I execute a PowerShell script (.ps1) via command line, it prefixes the script with a few headers, such as:

```
powershell.exe -File "C:\path\to\powershell.ps1"

GAC    Version        Location                                                                                         
---    -------        --------                                                                                         
True   v4.0.30319     C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Windows.Forms\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089...
```

I don't want to hide all output from the PowerShell script, as it does echo some useful information. I just would like to hide these headers so they do not appear on my screen or mixed in with the logs when the script runs.

If it matters, I'm using whatever PowerShell is built in to Windows 10.

Comment: Some line in your script is outputting an object with those properties.  This is how `Write-Output` displays objects by default.  You need to figure out which command in the script is outputting that object, and either redirect it or convert to string.  See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34143315/lower-verbosity-of-powershell-command-to-minimal-form/34143713#34143713 for ways to do this.

Comment: `[System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName` -> `Add-Type`

Comment: @PetSerAl this was my problem exactly. I changed `[system.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("System.Windows.Forms")` to `Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Windows.Forms` and that's all I needed. I'm new to PowerShell and was copy & pasting stuff I found, and didn't know this API was deprecated. Please turn your comment into an answer and I will mark it as Accepted. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Likely this happens due to call to `[System.Reflection.Assembly]::Load` / `LoadFile` / `LoadFrom` / `LoadWithPartialName` method. This methods return `Assembly` object, that them have load. Since PowerShell return value from every statement, not just explicit `return` statement, you need to explicitly ignore that `Assembly` object, so it does not get printed on console. Although, I suggest you to use `Add-Type` PowerShell cmdlet to load assemblies:

```
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Windows.Forms
```

Answer (score 3):

To hide the return value from the LoadFile method you have couple options:

- use **Out-Null** command - I think the most popular approach
- redirect output to the **$null** - also very obvious way to do it
- assign value to the **$null** - it is ok
- cast result to **$void** - this is really the trick

Below you can check all approaches. I created the function which loads 5 times assembly and use on each but last above methods. As you can see four information disappeared.

[image: Hiding Load file result in console]